# Make tags from text and textarea fields content with javascript

Tags: javascript, text, tags, textarea, auto-update

Is there a way to select the content from a text field, textarea field and some custom text, combine all the content and auto update a textarea field with that content but the words to be separated by comma like this:

- content text field: `Samsung tv`;
- context textarea field: `Led Smart tv`;
- custom text: `check the price`;

The result: a textarea field will auto update with this:

> Samsung, tv, Led, Smart, tv, check, the, price?

I have this code to update content from text to textarea but i don't know how to put that comma after each word:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function update(elem) { 
                document.getElementById('textareaDescription').value = " check price for " + elem.value ;  
            }
        </script>
Text: <input type="text" onchange="update(this)">
        <br>
        Textarea auto update : <textarea name="" id="textareaDescription" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you've already accepted an answer, I'd like to suggest this alternative:

```
function updateValue(els, output){
    // creates an empty array
    var textArray = [];

    /* iterates through the `els` array and if the value is not
       an empty string, splits the value at the white-spaces
       and pushes the array of values to the `textArray` */
    for (var i=0,len=els.length; i<len; i++){
        if (els[i].value !== ''){
            textArray.push(els[i].value.split(/\s/));
        }
    }

    /* makes the value of the `output` (textarea) equal to the 
       comma-separated string of words from the inputs, and
       adds a full-stop/period to the end of the 'sentence' */
    output.value = textArray.join(',') + '.';
}

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    output = document.getElementById('result'),
    els = [];

// makes an array from the `inputs` nodeList 
for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i<len; i++) {
    els.push(inputs[i]);
}

// assigns the function to call
for (var i = 0, len = els.length; i<len; i++) {
    els[i].onkeyup = function(e){
        updateValue(els, result);
    };
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XwBmQ/).

---

**Edited** to address question left by OP (in comments, below):

> At `var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input')` I can't put to get element by `id`, not by tag name?

Of course you can. You've a number of options as to how to collect the relevant elements on which you want to act; in the examples I'll just put those elements into the `els` variable, though; since that's already the one passed to the function (but adjust to taste in your own code).

First, to use `document.getElementById()`:

```
var els = [document.getElementById('one'),document.getElementById('two')];
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XwBmQ/6/) (note the removal of the first `for` loop, which was used to push relevant nodes into the `els` array).

Second, you can use an array to contain the `id` of those elements upon which you want to act:

```
/* not every browser has access to `indexOf()` for arrays, so an
   alternative is defined */

function inArray(needle,haystack) {
    // use native version if possible:
    if ([].indexOf !== undefined){
        return haystack.indexOf(needle);
    }
    // otherwise use custom approach:
    else {
        for (var i=0,len=haystack.length; i<len; i++){
            if (needle == haystack[i]){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    output = document.getElementById('result'),
    // array of the `id`s of the elements you want to use:
    elementIdsToUse = ['one','two'],
    els = [];

for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i<len; i++) {
    // if the `inputs[i]` node's `id` is in the array of `id`s...
    if (inArray(inputs[i].id,elementIdsToUse) > -1){
        // push that node to the `els` array:
        els.push(inputs[i]);
    }
}

for (var i = 0, len = els.length; i<len; i++) {
    els[i].onkeyup = function(e){
        updateValue(els, result);
    };
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XwBmQ/8/).

Third, you can, of course, use class-names (again, using `indexOf()`):

```
for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i<len; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].className.indexOf('useThis') > -1){
        els.push(inputs[i]);
    }
}

for (var i = 0, len = els.length; i<len; i++) {
    els[i].onkeyup = function(e){
        updateValue(els, result);
    };
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XwBmQ/2/).

And, finally, after a change of heart; a way to extend the `Array` prototype, to supply the `Array.indexOf()` method if it doesn't exist in the current browser:

```
Array.prototype.indexOf = Array.prototype.indexOf || function(needle) {
    for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i<len; i++){
        if (this[i] == needle){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
};
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XwBmQ/10/).

Which allows `Array.indexOf()` to be called directly, rather than (as above) having to needlessly use *two* function calls in unsupporting browsers (and testing for its existence *each time*) to successfully use *one* function.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed; I'm glad to have been of help to you :)

Comment: At `var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input')` i can't put to get element by id, not by tag name? Because i want to take content only from certain fields like from textarea.

Comment: You can indeed; see the edits for a few options/alternatives.

Comment: You're quite welcome; see the last update for a slightly modified approach to supplying `Array.indexOf()` for browsers that don't already implement such.

Answer (score 0):

variable1 + "," + variable2 + "," + variablenth.
Is that what you are trying to figure out?

Comment: Yes, like that.. and variable is one one word from text field content. I just want to take the content from text field and separate each word by comma and then put it in the textarea. I think i'll manage to da the rest after i make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your update function:

```
// replace
var myVal = elem.value
var regex = new RegExp(' ', 'g');
myVal = myVal.replace(regex,", ");
document.getElementById('textareaDescription').value = " check price for " + myVal ;
```

Comment: This code does't put comma in the custom text, only in myVal, but thank you!

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood your question now - you say you want to put the "check the price" as comma separated as well?

Comment: Exactly. Samy's code works.. but now i need to figure out how to take content from more text and textarea fields.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your update function like below

```
        function update(elem) { 
          var tosplit = "check price for " + elem.value ;
           //Get another field value, replace anotherfieldid with your actual field
           //You can add any number of fields like this. 
            var anotherfield =  document.getElementById('anotherfieldid').value 
            tosplit =  tosplit+anotherfield; 
          var text =tosplit.split(" ");
          document.getElementById('textareaDescription').value = text ;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! This works! Any ideea how to get elem.value from 2 or more fields?

Comment: Now there is a problem: i enter some text in the text field then textareaDescription updates fine.. but when i enter some text in anotherfieldid, nothing happens.. if i delete the content from text field, textareaDescription updates with the anotherfieldid content and the custom text.